# Search via object property

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a SidebarBox class which has a person as a property. I would like to get all SidebarBoxes based on the person.
For this I have created the following repositoy:

```
public interface SidebarRepository extends Neo4jRepository<SidebarBox, Long> {
    List<SidebarBox> findAllByPerson_Id(Long personId);
    List<SidebarBox> findAllByPerson(Person person);
}
```

If I search via `findAllByPerson_Id` I get no entry at all and if I do via `findAllByPerson` the program crashes with the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at de.skillkiller.persondb.PersondbApplication.main(PersondbApplication.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: The property 'null' is not mapped to a Graph property!
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jPersistentProperty.getPropertyName(DefaultNeo4jPersistentProperty.java:247) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.CypherQueryCreator.toCypherProperty(CypherQueryCreator.java:549) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.CypherQueryCreator.createImpl(CypherQueryCreator.java:385) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.CypherQueryCreator.create(CypherQueryCreator.java:240) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.CypherQueryCreator.create(CypherQueryCreator.java:85) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.PartTreeNeo4jQuery.prepareQuery(PartTreeNeo4jQuery.java:69) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractNeo4jQuery.execute(AbstractNeo4jQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.findAllByPerson(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at de.skillkiller.persondb.PersondbApplication.lambda$demo$0(PersondbApplication.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2021-02-23 18:51:36.308  INFO 34603 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-23 18:51:36.311  INFO 34603 --- [           main] org.neo4j.driver.Driver                  : Closing driver instance 1555928242
2021-02-23 18:51:36.313  INFO 34603 --- [           main] org.neo4j.driver.ConnectionPool          : Closing connection pool towards localhost:7687
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:40261', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

CommandLineRunner (shorted):

```
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setFirstname("Dieter");
            person.setLastname("Zufall");

            personRepository.save(person);

            SidebarBox sidebarBox = new SidebarBox("Test", person, new ArrayList<>());
            sidebarBox.addInformation(new SidebarBoxEntry("Key", "Nein"));
            sidebarBox.addInformation(new SidebarBoxEntry("AKey", "Nein"));

            sidebarRepository.save(sidebarBox);
            List<SidebarBox> a = sidebarRepository.findAll();
            List<SidebarBox> b = sidebarRepository.findAllByPerson_Id(person.getId());
            List<SidebarBox> c = sidebarRepository.findAllByPerson(person);
```

Person:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Node
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person extends BasicNode {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String comment;
}
```

SidebarBox:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Node
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SidebarBox extends BasicNode{
    private String title;
    private Person person;
    private List<SidebarBoxEntry> information = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addInformation(SidebarBoxEntry entry) {
        information.add(entry);
    }

    public void removeInformation(SidebarBoxEntry entry) {
        information.remove(entry);
    }
}
```

Basic Node:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BasicNode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @DateLong
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date changedAt = new Date();

    @DateLong
    @CreatedDate
    private Date enteredAt = new Date();
}
```

Unfortunately I don't understand how to fix this error.
Can you tell me how I can realize such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the inheritance with the `BasicNode` there was a bug in Spring Data Neo4j that took the wrong meta-information and in your case did not create the right type (`SidebarBox`).
An update will be available later this month. In the mean-time you could check the `6.0.6-SNAPSHOT` version of SDN.
I created an example with your code https://github.com/meistermeier/neo4j-issues-examples/tree/master/relatedIdQuery
And using this very version, it works with `List<SidebarBox> findAllByPerson_Id(Long personId)`

For the upcoming 6.1 release we have planned to introduce a "find by object" to also give you more flexibility.